# How to access a checkbox that's in a form in a Django template in view function in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have an HTML file that has a form element. Inside the form I have a checkbox. How can I access that checkbox value when ticked inside the views in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send post request you can access all data sent from dictionary request.POST.

You should probably first read django forms documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: i know that we have to use request.POST  but how to do it.And the link you suggested if for form generation by Django using models

Comment: To send a post request there should be form in your template with says that method is post, and there should be a button of type submit. When you click it the post request will be sent to specified view.